# Oracle SQL - Selecting First Row for each ID

Tags: query, oracle-12c, greatest-n-per-group, syntax

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying to pick the first entry of the student population.
So, that I have one row for each ID.

| ID | DEGREE | AWARDED | ACADEMIC PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147 | GR | MS | 2022 |
| 147 | UG | BS | 2020 |
| 170 | GR | MA | 2023 |
| 170 | UG | BA | 2018 |

Expected output is

| ID | DEGREE | AWARDED | ACADEMIC PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147 | GR | MS | 2022 |
| 170 | GR | MA | 2023 |

Comment: WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = 1

Comment: What if there's a tie - the same `ACADEMIC PERIOD` more than once for the same `ID`?...is this possible and if so, how do you want it handled?

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM StudentDegrees sd
WHERE ACADEMIC_PERIOD = (
    SELECT MIN(ACADEMIC_PERIOD)
    FROM StudentDegrees
    WHERE ID = sd.ID
);
```

This should workout

Comment: I think by "*first*" OP means the latest `ACADEMIC PERIOD`. So I believe you want to use `MAX()` actually.

Comment: @J.D., I have used the query to get the order ascendingly; However, if the output is not the one he desires, he can use ```MAX()```.